# Pandas installed but not recognised by IDLE on Mac

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to Python.

I had installed Anaconda when I was practicing Python. Jupyter Notebooks was causing issues so I installed IDLE.

The installation of Python and Idle3 is in the same location.

```
(base) myname@myMac ~ % which python
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
(base) myname@myMac ~ % which idle3
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/idle3
```

Pandas is also installed in the same user

```
(base) myname@myMac~ % pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2023.3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas) (1.16.0)
```

In IDLE Shell 3.11.3

```
import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Additional Data that could help

```
(base) myname@myMac 3.11 % which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6 python3.11       
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
/Users/myname/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11
/usr/local/bin/python3.11
```

Pandas is working fine on Jupyter Notebook. Suggestions would be helpful.

I wanted to access the pandas module in python. I have checked other answers but none have been directing to this issue. If the installation is correct, pandas should be running fine.

Comment: Do you have python 3.11 in this location? ./opt/anaconda3/lib/

Comment: _pip3.11 install pandas_  resolved the issue. Also, as mentioned in the answer below _python3.11 -m pip install pandas_ would also work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your default Python version is 3.9. So when you use pip to install any library it uses the pip of python3.9. So you will have no problem importing pandas in IDLE Shell 3.9.* if you have 3.9 shell.

So to use the pip of python3.11 use ->

`python3.11 -m pip install pandas`